# Paging in Cassandra with spring-boot-data

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, paging, datastax

How is it possible to page through retrieved rows with spring-boot-data? I am aware of the documentation from Datastax:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/paging/

My repository interface:

```
public interface DeviceRepository extends CassandraRepository<Device> {
    Device findByFieldDeviceId(String fieldDeviceId);
}
```

My Service class:

```
public Device findByFieldDeviceId(final String fieldDeviceId) {
    return deviceRepository.findByFieldDeviceId(fieldDeviceId);
}
```

My Pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I dont see how i can extract and set the paging state from the result.

Answer (score 2):

Spring-data-cassandra 2.0 GA (Kay) release supports for pagination with Cassandra.

check the PR for sample code https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pull/114